# Update UI element of different class from a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to update the UI form different class which is inside a thread.

Relevant code is:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void encryptButtonPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkValues() == true)
    {
        updateConsole("Starting Encryption...");

        Thread encryptThread = new Thread(encrypt);
        encryptThread.Start();
    }
}
```

encrypt function

```
public void encrypt()
{
    Encrypt encrypt = new Encrypt(this.KeyFileContent, this.SourcePath, this.DestinationPath, this);
    encrypt.start();
}
```

update console function

```
public void updateConsole(String text)
{
    consoleWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    consoleWindow.AppendText(text);

    consoleWindow.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

**Encrypt.cs**

```
public byte[] key;
public String source;
public String destination;
public MainWindow mainWindow;

public Encrypt(byte[] key, String source, String destination, MainWindow mainWindow) 
{
    this.key = key;
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
}
```

start function

```
public void start()
{
    mainWindow.updateConsole("Updating form thread");
}
```

I have tried

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        mainWindow.updateConsole("Updating form thread");
    });
```

but no use.

Comment: `but no use.` What does it mean?

Comment: it means the last thing i tried does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Do you see nothing, an error, does it crash?

Comment: Do you get an exception even when you use `Dispatcher.Invoke`? What is the error?

Comment: i have tried `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() => this.mainWindow.updateConsole(s)));` and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting the whole `mainWindow` you should be only pass in the stuff you need. In this case the updateConsole method.

change the start method to this:

```
public void start(Action<string> updateConsole)
{
    updateConsole.Invoke("Updating form thread");
}
```

then you should be able to make pass in the method like this:

```
public void encrypt()
{
    Encrypt encrypt = new Encrypt(this.KeyFileContent, this.SourcePath, this.DestinationPath, this);
    start(updateConsole);
}
```

Lastly you don't need to inject in the `mainWindow` to your Encrypt class any longer:

```
public byte[] key;
public String source;
public String destination;

public Encrypt(byte[] key, String source, String destination) 
{
    this.key = key;
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
}
```

Comment: It is an elaborate solution but for time being, my code is running :) . I will keep it for future reference. Thanks :)

Comment: Also i noticed you don't use databinding to your `consoleWindow`.
Maybe you should read into MVVM if this is a larger project :-)
[MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Comment: this is just a small project. Thanks for ur suggestion :)

Comment: plus i am beginner